# Composable function not being executed after mutable value change

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, mutable, exoplayer2.x

So I got this line of code:

```
fun LiveTrainingScreen(viewModel: LiveTrainingViewModel = viewModel()) {


Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(PaddingStatic.Small).zIndex(2f)) {
    //Large Video Display
    //here
    var videoLink = remember { mutableStateOf(LiveTrainingViewModel.cockPitRight) }

    val exoPlayerCamera1 = viewModel.GetCameraPlayer(videoLink.value)


    DisposableEffect(
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(RoundedSizeStatic.Medium))
                .clickable { videoLink = mutableStateOf(LiveTrainingViewModel.mapCamera) },
            factory = {
                PlayerView(viewModel.context).apply {
                    player = exoPlayerCamera1
                    useController = false
                    resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL

                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    ) {
        onDispose {
            exoPlayerCamera1.release()
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I click on the video element, the code is not being re-executed when I change the mediaItem Uri, because the video frame keeps displaying the same video.

And I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Through mutablestate manual string change, re-execute code to change video display from the internet

Comment: What and where is `mediaItem`.

Comment: mediaItem is used to fetch the video from the internet, and it is created through the videoLink: String that i am passing to the GetCameraPlayer(videoLink.value) function

Comment: Can you add the code for that flow to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some reason exoplayer doesn't update when a State update is done.

So I tried to set the MediaItem for the second time which worked fine

```
.clickable {  exoPlayerCamera1.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(LiveTrainingViewModel.mapCamera))
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating another mutableState (`State<String>`), instead of updating the current one the `remember` already calculated, and you also haven't specified any `key` to `remember` for it to `re-calculate` to tell your composable that something has changed for it to `re-compose`

```
...
.clickable { videoLink = mutableStateOf(LiveTrainingViewModel.mapCamera) }
...
```

Either you de-structure the value the remember returns like this, you can then have access to its value and a lambda that you can invoke to pass a new value for your composable to re-compose.

```
val (videoLinkValue, setValue) = remember { mutableStateOf(LiveTrainingViewModel.cockPitRight) }
```

updating it like this

```
...
.clickable { setValue (LiveTrainingViewModel.mapCamera) }
...
```

observing the value using the first de-structured component

```
val exoPlayerCamera1 = viewModel.GetCameraPlayer(videoLinkValue)
```

Or you can just simply do this

```
val videoLink by remember { mutableStateOf(LiveTrainingViewModel.cockPitRight) }
```

and just update it via `.onClick` like this

```
.clickable { videoLink = LiveTrainingViewModel.mapCamera }
```

Comment: I will check it out, I thought I already tried this though. But my emulator won't boot for now hahahaha as always

Comment: didn't work sadly, I though best practice is changing the video with the State functionality but I will try it in a different way now. I think it has something to do with Exoplayer